# Regex for prices in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I want to create a method to find a string with price and destruct to 3 values: currency, amount and isCurrency at front. I created the method:

```
fun extractCurrencyAndAmount(input: String): Triple<String, String, Boolean> {
    val regex = Regex("^([0-9]+)\\s*([^0-9]+)?|([^0-9]+)?\\s*([0-9]+)\$")
    val matchResult = regex.find(input)

    return if (matchResult != null) {
        val (before, amount, after) = matchResult.destructured
        val currency = if (after.isEmpty()) before else after
        val isCurrencyAtFront = after.isEmpty()
        Triple(currency, amount, isCurrencyAtFront)
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input format")
    }
}
```

But I get an empty amount for price "$100" and false for isCurrencyAtFront.

For price for example "100 $" I get a good amount and currency, but wrong isCurrencyAtFront - true.

What is wrong is in my regex?

Comment: First of all, if you want to match a whole string, wrap the alternatives: ``Regex("""^(?:([0-9]+)\s*([^0-9]+)?|([^0-9]+)?\s*([0-9]+))$""")``

Comment: I think [.destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/-destructured/) gives back the capture group values, and with the alternation you have 4 capture groups instead of 2. So for `100 $` with works, but for `$100` you have to check the other 2 capture groups as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code return the same value

Comment: Of course. It is just a pattern to show how to correctly anchor two alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got four capturing groups in the regular expression pattern, but you get only three when destructuring. You need a pattern that matches a part of string before the numeric value, after it and the numeric value itself, thus, totalling three groups. Else, the code would get more complicated.

I suggest using

```kotlin
fun extractCurrencyAndAmount(input: String): Triple<String, String, Boolean> {
    val regex = Regex("""^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$""")
    val matchResult = regex.find(input)

    return if (matchResult != null) {
        val (before, amount, after) = matchResult.destructured
        val currency = if (after.isEmpty()) before.strip() else after.strip()
        val isCurrencyAtFront = after.strip().isEmpty()
        Triple(currency, amount, isCurrencyAtFront)
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input format")
    }
}
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/wi48VI).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5lDQ8/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D*)` - Group 1: zero or more non-digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(\D*)` - Group 1: zero or more non-digits
- `$` - end of string.

The use of `.strip()` makes the pattern simpler as we do not need to account for whitespaces there and use `\s*` with other twists.

Answer (score 1):

Using [destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/-destructured/) gives you 4 capture groups, either group 1 and group 2 or group 3 and group 4.

You can check if the `amountStart` in the example code is not empty for the pattern at the start of the string, else you have the 2 groups at the end of the string.

Note that `[^0-9]+` can match spaces only and `\s` can also match newlines, so you will have to account for that.

As you now which part is at the beginnen or end, you can pass true or false.

```
fun extractCurrencyAndAmount(input: String): Triple<String, String, Boolean> {
    val regex = Regex("""^([0-9]+)\s*([^0-9]*)|([^0-9]*?)\s*([0-9]+)$""")
    val matchResult = regex.find(input)

    return if (matchResult != null) {
        val (amountStart, afterStart, afterEnd, amountEnd) = matchResult.destructured

        if (amountStart.isNotEmpty()) Triple(amountStart, afterStart, true)
        else Triple(afterEnd, amountEnd, false) 
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input format")
    }
}
```

[Kotlin demo](https://pl.kotl.in/SMu3oG5I0)

What you might also do is make the pattern more specific by matching the currency listing them in a character class instead of using `[^0-9]+`

In this case the currency is mandatory, and `\h` matches horizontal whitespace characters.

```
^([0-9]+)\h*([$€]?)|([$€]?)\h*([0-9]+)$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0KwAYh/1).

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem with your regex is addressed in other posts and in case you're looking for an alternative solution(which avoids `regex`) I can think of a way in which we:

1. Iterate through the input string once and keep track of the starting and ending indices for both the amount and currency.
2. Then extract the `amount` and `currency` using *those indices and determine if the currency is at the front or not*.
   A sample of the above step would look like:

```kotlin
// init
var amountStart = -1
var amountEnd = -1
var currencyStart = -1
var currencyEnd = -1

input.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
  if (char.isDigit()) {
     if (amountStart == -1) {
         amountStart = index
     }
     amountEnd = index
  } else if (!char.isWhitespace()) {
      if (currencyStart == -1) {
         currencyStart = index
      }
      currencyEnd = index
   }
 }
 if (listOf(amountStart, amountEnd, currencyStart, currencyEnd).any { it == -1 }) 
   {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input format")
   }

val amount = input.substring(amountStart, amountEnd + 1)
val currency = input.substring(currencyStart, currencyEnd + 1)
val isCurrencyAtFront = currencyStart < amountStart

return Triple(currency, amount, isCurrencyAtFront)
```

***[Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/SzpwLj)***